# Google Cloud Function JS Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed the following JavaScript Google Cloud Function which sends a notification to a device triggered by the .onCreate call. The function seems to be working fine but I am getting the following console error and I am struggling to figure out exactly what is the issue:

Error:

> TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
>       at Function.keys ()
>       at admin.database.ref.once.then (/srv/index.js:274:39)
>       at 
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)

Cloud function:

```
exports.notifyNewInvite = functions.database.ref('/invites/{pushId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {

  const complimentSnap = snap.val(); //snap.after.val();

  const fromId = complimentSnap.fromId;
  const toId = complimentSnap.toId;

  console.log('fromId: ', fromId);
  console.log('toId: ', toId);

  // Get the list of device notification tokens.
  const getDeviceTokensPromise = admin.database().ref('/fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registrationtokens').once('value');

  return admin.database().ref('/fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registrationtokens').once('value').then((userTok) => {

    const registrationTokens = Object.keys(userTok.val())

    console.log('registrationTokens', registrationTokens);

    return admin.database().ref('/users/' + fromId).once('value').then((userDoc) => {

      const user = userDoc.val();

      const senderName = user.firstName
      console.log('senderName: ', senderName);

      const notificationBody = 'Message text here...'


        //build media messages notification
        const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: "I'm " + senderName,
              body: notificationBody
            },
            data: {
              SENDER_NAME: senderName,
              SENDER_ID: fromId,
              NOTIFICATION: 'invite'

            }//end data
        }//end payload

        const options = {
          content_available: true
        }

        //send message
        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(registrationTokens, payload, options).then( response => {

          const stillRegisteredTokens = registrationTokens

          response.results.forEach((result, index) => {

                    const error = result.error

                    if (error) {

                        const failedRegistrationToken = registrationTokens[index]

                        console.error('blah', failedRegistrationToken, error)

                        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' || error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {

                                const failedIndex = stillRegisteredTokens.indexOf(failedRegistrationToken)

                                if (failedIndex > -1) {
                                    stillRegisteredTokens.splice(failedIndex, 1)
                                }

                            }
                    }

                })//end forEach

                var  validTokens = {};

                stillRegisteredTokens.forEach(function(element){
                  console.log('valid token: ', element);
                  validTokens[element] = true;
                });

                return admin.database().ref('fcmtokens/' + toId + '/registrationtokens').set(validTokens)


        })//end sendToDevice


    })//end return-then

  })//end return-then

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `userTok.val()` is returning `null`, which means that DataSnapshot is empty(no data). [More info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.DataSnapshot.html#val)

```
// code ... 
const tokData = userTok.val();

if(!tokDData) {
    console.error('No registration tokens');
    return; //  
}

// code ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything is working fine you can put a null check just to be failsafe and getting rid of console issue on `userTok.val()`

```
const registrationTokens = Object.keys(userTok.val())
```